# hide UIButton image

Tags: ios, uibutton

I implemented this method to make flash button, but doing the touch of the button stops working well.

```
-(void)imageAnimation:(UIButton *)imagen{
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    imagen.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.5 options:0 animations:^{
        imagen.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [self imageAnimation:imagen];
    }];
}];
```

}

You know as I can do to make the image flickers button but the button always is active and visible touch that works well?

Comment: Have you tried `[imagen setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]` right after setting the alpha to 0?  I'm sure there are better ways of doing what you want, but that might work in the short term.

Comment: if you've tried it and the touch is not recognized at first, I seek to recognize the quiet, degas touch the button, and putting that keeps happening that after trying a lot of times just being pressed alfinal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about animating a UIImageView's alpha and using a transparent UIButton over it? Alternatively, you could use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the UIImageView itself, though I think the alpha=0 issue will reoccur in this scenario as well.

Comment: you are a genius, I had not thought about it but was super intuitive